# Seaborn color palette with Pandas groupby and .plot function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am having a very frustrating problem when trying to plot some data with a seaborn color palette.  My workflow is to perform a groupby operation on my dataframe, and plot each group as its own curve using code like this:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_style('whitegrid')
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(16, 6))

inner = d.groupby(['dr_min', 'dr_max'])
n = len(inner)
cmap = sns.color_palette("Blues", n_colors=n)
inner.plot(x='limit_l', y='lccdf', ax=ax1, color=cmap, legend=False)
inner.plot(x='limit_r', y='rcdf', ax=ax2, color=cmap, legend=False)
```

I expect to see a curve for each one of my groupby parameters with clear shades from the color map, as seen here:
[image]

Instead, my curves look below, with no color grade at all.  Can anyone help me understanding why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly you want to iterate over the groupby object to chose the color for each individual line.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

a = np.tile(np.arange(0,10),5)
b = np.linspace(0,1,len(a))
c = np.repeat(list("ABCDE"), 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":a, "y":b, "c":c})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = sns.color_palette("Blues", n_colors=5)

inner = df.groupby(["c"])

for i, (n, gr) in enumerate(inner):
    gr.plot(x="x", y="y", ax=ax, color=cmap[i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This does generate the curves properly, but I don't think looping should be necessary here.  This feels like a workaround to me.

Comment: A workaround for a feature that is not implement by pandas, yes. You may ask why pandas did not implement the option to supply several colors to the `color` argument. And the answer is probably that this would make it necessary to rewrite the plotting function completely, because as it is now, `color` is simply passed on the matplotlib line plot and a `Line2D` object in matplotlib has exactly one single color associated to it. Hence it is necessary to plot several curves individually and looping is a convenient way to do so.